# Gstreamer stream mp4 video over RTSP endlessly

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, rtsp-server

I try to stream a mp4 video in a loop over RTSP. To achieve this I  modified the example code from [test-appsrc2.c](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-appsrc2.c). The idea is to restart the pipeline once I have received the EOS (end of stream) for the generating pipeline.

I successfully receive the EOS but I am not able to either rewind the pipeline nor to play another video. What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/app.h>

#include <gst/rtsp-server/rtsp-server.h>

#include <thread>

typedef struct
{
  GstElement *generator_pipe;
  GstElement *vid_appsink;
  GstElement *vid_appsrc;
  GstElement *aud_appsink;
  GstElement *aud_appsrc;
} MyContext;

gboolean bus_callback(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, gpointer data)
{
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  GstElement *vin;
  GstElement *pipeline = GST_ELEMENT(data);
  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg))
  {
  case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
    g_print("GST_MESSAGE_EOS: %s\n", gst_message_type_get_name (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)));
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    vin = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (pipeline), "vin");
    g_print ("vin: %p\n",vin);
    if(vin)
    {
      gst_util_set_object_arg (G_OBJECT (vin), "location", "video02.mp4");

    }
    /*
    if (!gst_element_seek(pipeline,
                          1.0, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH,
                          GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, 0, // 1 seconds (in nanoseconds)
                          GST_SEEK_TYPE_NONE, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE))
    {
      g_print("Seek failed!\n");
    }
    */
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    break;
  case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
  break;
  default:
    g_print("got message %s\n", gst_message_type_get_name (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)));
    break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

/* called when we need to give data to an appsrc */
static void need_data (GstElement * appsrc, guint unused, MyContext * ctx)
{
  GstSample *sample;
  GstFlowReturn ret;
  sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample (GST_APP_SINK (ctx->vid_appsink));
  if (sample) {
    GstBuffer *buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer (sample);
    GstSegment *seg = gst_sample_get_segment (sample);
    GstClockTime pts, dts;
    /* Convert the PTS/DTS to running time so they start from 0 */
    pts = GST_BUFFER_PTS (buffer);
    if (GST_CLOCK_TIME_IS_VALID (pts))
      pts = gst_segment_to_running_time (seg, GST_FORMAT_TIME, pts);

    dts = GST_BUFFER_DTS (buffer);
    if (GST_CLOCK_TIME_IS_VALID (dts))
      dts = gst_segment_to_running_time (seg, GST_FORMAT_TIME, dts);
    if (buffer) {
      /* Make writable so we can adjust the timestamps */
      buffer = gst_buffer_copy (buffer);
      GST_BUFFER_PTS (buffer) = pts;
      GST_BUFFER_DTS (buffer) = dts;
      g_signal_emit_by_name (appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
    }

    /* we don't need the appsink sample anymore */
    gst_sample_unref (sample);
  }
}

static void ctx_free (MyContext * ctx)
{
  g_print ("ctx_free\n");
  gst_element_set_state (ctx->generator_pipe, GST_STATE_NULL);

  gst_object_unref (ctx->generator_pipe);
  gst_object_unref (ctx->vid_appsrc);
  gst_object_unref (ctx->vid_appsink);
  g_free (ctx);
}

/* called when a new media pipeline is constructed. We can query the
 * pipeline and configure our appsrc */
static void media_configure (GstRTSPMediaFactory * factory, GstRTSPMedia * media, gpointer user_data)
{
  GstElement *element, *appsrc, *appsink;
  GstCaps *caps;
  MyContext *ctx;

  ctx = g_new0 (MyContext, 1);

  gchar* pipeline_description = g_strdup_printf("filesrc name=vin location=%s : qtdemux : h264parse : appsink name=vid max-buffers=3 drop=false",(char*)user_data);

  /* This pipeline generates H264 video. The appsinks are kept small so that if delivery is slow,
   * encoded buffers are dropped as needed.*/
  ctx->generator_pipe = gst_parse_launch(pipeline_description,NULL);

  /* make sure the data is freed when the media is gone */
  g_object_set_data_full (G_OBJECT (media), "rtsp-extra-data", ctx,(GDestroyNotify) ctx_free);

  /* get the element (bin) used for providing the streams of the media */
  element = gst_rtsp_media_get_element (media);

  /* Find the app source video, and configure it, connect to the
   * signals to request data */
  /* configure the caps of the video */

  // TODO identify the caps from the stream
  caps = gst_caps_new_simple ("video/x-h264",
      "stream-format", G_TYPE_STRING, "byte-stream",
      "alignment", G_TYPE_STRING, "au",
      "width", G_TYPE_INT, 2880, "height", G_TYPE_INT, 1860,
      "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 30, 1, NULL);



  ctx->vid_appsrc = appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name_recurse_up (GST_BIN (element), "videosrc");
  ctx->vid_appsink = appsink = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (ctx->generator_pipe), "vid");


  gst_util_set_object_arg (G_OBJECT (appsrc), "format", "time");
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsrc), "caps", caps, NULL);
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (appsink), "caps", caps, NULL);
  /* install the callback that will be called when a buffer is needed */
  g_signal_connect (appsrc, "need-data", (GCallback) need_data, ctx);
  gst_caps_unref (caps);


  GstBus *bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (ctx->generator_pipe));
  gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_callback, ctx->generator_pipe);
  gst_object_unref (bus);


  gst_element_set_state (ctx->generator_pipe, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  gst_object_unref (element);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GMainLoop *loop;
  GstRTSPServer *server;
  GstRTSPMountPoints *mounts;
  GstRTSPMediaFactory *factory;

  if(argc < 2) {
    g_print("The video filename is missing\n");
    g_print("%s <filename>\n",argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

  /* create a server instance */
  server = gst_rtsp_server_new ();

  /* get the mount points for this server, every server has a default object
   * that be used to map uri mount points to media factories */
  mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points (server);

  /* make a media factory for a test stream. The default media factory can use
   * gst-launch syntax to create pipelines.
   * any launch line works as long as it contains elements named pay%d. Each
   * element with pay%d names will be a stream */
  factory = gst_rtsp_media_factory_new ();
  gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch (factory, "( appsrc name=videosrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )");

  gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_shared(factory, TRUE);
  /* notify when our media is ready, This is called whenever someone asks for
   * the media and a new pipeline with our appsrc is created */
  g_signal_connect (factory, "media-configure", (GCallback) media_configure, argv[1]);

  /* attach the test factory to the /test url */
  gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory (mounts, "/test", factory);

  /* don't need the ref to the mounts anymore */
  g_object_unref (mounts);

  /* attach the server to the default maincontext */
  gst_rtsp_server_attach (server, NULL);

  /* start serving */
  g_print ("stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test\n");
  g_main_loop_run (loop);

  return 0;
}
```

The log of my application run with `GST_DEBUG=4` can be found here: https://gist.github.com/graugans/a989a78dd7f2c4083e881bb46ce04651

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 with Gstreamer 1.16.3